# Mysql will not start - "cant change permissions of ca-key.pem"?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

Trying to start our mysql service but getting an error:

Nov 19 09:15:57 MIDBSQLMASTER mysqld[11497]: mysqld: Can't change permissions of the file 'ca-key.pem' (Errcode: 1 - Operation not permitted)
Nov 19 09:15:57 MIDBSQLMASTER mysqld[11497]: 2019-11-19T09:15:57.054122Z 0 [ERROR] Could not set file permission for ca-key.pem

Full Log - [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wCVDEFCc)

Would anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: You do not provide enough context for your problem, but generally, an upgrade to mysql:5.7.16 fixes this issue. See https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/302 .

Comment: Hi there,  Unfortunatly i have no other context,  Came in to work this morning with this error above. - My mysql version is 5.7.28

Comment: Sorry i should also mention it is not running on an azure service,  Its a Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual machine running locally on our network

Comment: You are trying to run mysql under SSL so change the ca file to the same user and group that you are running mysql under

Comment: try this hack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575988/wsl2-fail-to-change-file-permissions

Comment: For anyone who gets such error while running mysql docker image on WSL, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610256/chmod-wsl-bash-doesnt-work/50856772#50856772